# ETC1 Support on android alpha problem (GLSL cocos2d-x)

Tags: c++, shaders, glsl

I want to support etc1 in my game, but somehow it doesn't work
(I'm using cocos2d-x

C++

```
 GLProgram* glp = new GLProgram();

glp->initWithVertexShaderFilename("testv.vsh", "test.fsh");
glp->addAttribute(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_POSITION, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_POSITION);
glp->addAttribute(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_COLOR, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_COLOR);
glp->addAttribute(GLProgram::ATTRIBUTE_NAME_TEX_COORD, GLProgram::VERTEX_ATTRIB_TEX_COORD);
glp->link();
glp->updateUniforms();

Texture2D* tex = Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImage("MenuButton_alpha.pkm");

GL::bindTexture2DN(1, tex->getName());    
GLuint t1Location = glGetUniformLocation(glp->getProgram(), "tex1");
glp->setUniformLocationWith1i(t1Location, 1);

MySprite->setShaderProgram(glp);
```

.vsh

```
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord;
attribute vec4 a_color;


varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord2;


uniform sampler2D tex1;

void main()
{
    gl_Position = CC_MVPMatrix * a_position;
    v_fragmentColor = a_color;
    v_texCoord = a_texCoord;
    v_texCoord2 = v_texCoord;

}
```

.fsh

```
varying vec4 v_fragmentColor;   
varying vec2 v_texCoord;
varying vec2 v_texCoord2;

uniform sampler2D tex1;


void main()
{
    vec3 tex = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord).rgb;

    float alpha = texture2D(CC_Texture1, v_texCoord2).a;

    gl_FragColor = vec4(tex.rgb,alpha);
}
```

Somehow it shows my sprite in the middle but the transparent part is black.
can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You need to check two things:

**1.Texture** **and** **Shader**

ETC1 doesn't support alpha.

You'd have to use a separate texture read (which you seem to be doing on texture2D(CC_Texture1, v_texCoord2). You can use tools to extract alpha channel from a RGBA texture and use a single texCoord for both samplers. Your code could be something like this:

```
vec3 tex = texture2D(CC_Texture0, v_texCoord).rgb;
float alpha = texture2D(CC_Texture1, v_texCoord).a; <- use same coord
```

Check this link for more info on ETC1 and alpha: http://malideveloper.arm.com/develop-for-mali/sample-code/etcv1-texture-compression-and-alpha-channels/

**2. Blending**

You'll also need to set blending. I don't know how to do that in Cocos2D, but in OpenGL it would be something like this:

```
glEnable(GL_BLEND);
glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRCALPHA);
```

Now, if you want a texture compression that supports alpha you can use ETC2 (all opengl es 3 devices support it), and for better performance and quality ASTC. Not many devices support it now but the quality difference from ASTC to ETC1 is brutal, plus ASTC supports alpha.

Comment: does the z order matter?

Comment: float alpha = texture2D(CC_Texture1, v_texCoord).r; works for me but why?. .r = red channel , why it's not .a for alpha

Comment: what would be the beest way to support etc for all my sprites?

Comment: @Sleicreider the rendering order and z matters. You should render transparent objects from front-to-back. The .a or .r matter depends on the texture format you uploaded texture to gpu.